# couldn't find "libaw_video.so" react-native native android sdk integration

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

While creating a react-native module for Integrating some native android code and AAR files giving this error and app crashes.

Used this in app-level build.gradle

```
packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/*.so'
    }
```

and added all *.so files in jinLibs and write this in build.Gradle(one which is in my module "react-native-test-lib")

```
 sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['src/main/jnilibs']
        }
    }
```

The app crashes with the error "couldn't find libaw_video.so"

Comment: I have a similare issue for another library. Did you solved this?